# Deleting Local Accounts Only Deletes Half In Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am creating hundreds of local accounts for testing purposes. The problem is cleanup, when I run the command to delete all the temp accounts, it only deletes half of them.  "bca" is the account prefix, short for "bulk created account"

I run the count (everything done as admin)

```
Get-LocalUser | ? {$_.Name -like "bca*"} | Measure-Object
```

And I get count of 20

So I run the delete

```
Get-LocalUser | ? {$_.Name -like "bca*"} | Remove-LocalUser
```

Then I do the count again. Expecting 0. I get 10

I repeat the deletion, do the count, get 5, then 2, then 1 then finally 0.

**UPDATE:**

I was able to delete them all using the following command, from a comment below

`foreach($user in Get-LocalUser -Name "bca*") { Remove-LocalUser $user}`

BUT I am still curious why the original didn't work

Comment: I don't think you need `Where-Object` in this case. You could do `Get-LocalUser -Name "bca*"`. Also, have you tried a `foreach` loop to delete the users?

Comment: I have not tried a foreach loop. I wouldn't know how to set it up (I'm not so good with powershell)

The halving problem persists with the alternative format though
```PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-LocalUser -Name "bca*" | Remove-LocalUser
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-LocalUser -Name "bca*" | Measure-Object


Count    : 5
Average  :
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property :
```

Comment: I was able to delete them all using this
```foreach($user in Get-LocalUser -Name "bca*") { Remove-LocalUser $user}```
But I am still curious why the original one does every other line

Comment: The original deletes every other line because it first retrieves a list of items, and then iterates the list. Think about it - you have 5 items in a list, and you start a loop over them (indexes 0 to 4). The first iteration removes item 0 and shifts everthing down one, increments the index to 1, but is now pointing to what was originally at index 2 but is now at 1 because of the downward shift. Repeat again, and the current index is 2 but because of the two deleted items it's pointing at the original index 4. Work through that logic on a piece of paper if it's not clear what's happening.

Comment: @KenWhite: that is undoubtedly what's happening in the background, but is no clear explanation for why the `foreach` loop *does* work, then. In both cases, PowerShell ought to be running an enumerator. Maybe `Get-LocalUser` with a filter is kind enough to return an array? (I have no access to PowerShell at the moment.) `@(Get-LocalUser | ? {$_.Name -like "bca*"}) | Remove-LocalUser` should similarly work (forcing the results to materialize into an array first before passing them).

Comment: Since `Remove-LocalUser` can take an array of  localuser objects, `(Get-LocalUser | ? {$_.Name -like "bca*"}) | Remove-LocalUser` would likely fix your issue by piping in the entire `Get-LocalUser` result into `Remove-LocalUser`.

Comment: Looks like a bug in Get-LocalUser to me; make ten test users `0..9|%{new-localuser -Name "bca$_" -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 1 -AsPlainText -Force)}` then try `get-localuser bca* | remove-localuser -WhatIf`and it says it will remove every user, switch `-Whatif` to `-Verbose` and it only does remove half of them, in the pattern every other one. Wrap `Get-LocalUser` in parens and then it completes before the remove starts, and removes all of them. So I think Get-LocalUser is doing what Ken White describes internally when reading from the user list.

Comment: I don't know whether the first method is using an iterator or a simple loop, but the behavior indicates it's the latter. `foreach` definitely uses an iterator, and works as long as the GetNext returns something. I do know that when looping through a list and deleting items you need to reverse through the list (from end to beginning) to prevent the exact problem you're having from occurring.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: enumeration cannot strictly be called a bug, since it would be monstrously inefficient to always materialize everything in a pipeline just in case some later part ends up modifying the original collection (think reading lines from a huge file). Some collections are kind enough to implement change detection for this so they end up producing an error, but this is 1) overhead and 2) something someone has to consider and implement (potentially impossible if you're wrapping lower level OS enumerations). Having to materialize yourself is probably an acceptable tradeoff.

Comment: @LucTaylor Now that I think about it, you could just do `Remove-LocalUser -Name "bca*"`. Maybe it didn't work before due to the filtering somehow? Maybe try it without the `Where-Object` filter

Comment: @JeroenMostert in general I agree, but how defensible is it that "Get-LocalUser" should be "monstrously inefficient" to list all the local users? What are we talking, 5-10 in most cases and "hundreds" in this specific case? That's about the overhead of listing a directory with hundreds of files in it, right? Shouldn't be too hard for PS.